# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am refreshing display of time after every 1 seconds. I try to prefix that display with text from element `divMessage`. However, I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" error. However, the text of `divMessage` was assigned without any problems in the document ready function `($function())`. So, what is going on here?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    var loaded = false

    $(function(){
        ....
    $.post(window.location, {
        ....
    }).success(function(data){
        // I assign divMessage text here without any problems!
        loaded = true
    });

    function myTimer() 
    {
        var d = new Date()
        var dateTime = d.toLocaleTimeString()
        var divMessage = ''
        if (loaded) {
            // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" error here!
            divMessage = document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green\">" + 
               divMessage + ", " + dateTime + "</span>"; 
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

The elements are defined like this.

```
<div id="divMessage"><span style="color:yellow">some text</span></div>
<div id="div2"><span style="color:yellow">some text</span></div>
```

Comment: you need braces on the `if`

Comment: Typo @ `toLocaleTimeString`... Missing `e`

Comment: Is the bracketing a problem? You seem to have two sets of `})` in your `$(function`

Comment: With removing the second `})` brackets in your 'ready' function and the fixed typo it seems to work fine: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jm01bpbg/)
I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @HopefulLlama: That is because I forgot to remove those brackets when trying to present my original code in a simplified manner. But that isn't the problem.

Comment: your code, fixed brackets, is running on jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/berets/bg1u7w4n/
could be any other code portion are influencing your output ?

Comment: @Luca: Indeed the problem was something else, as I was using replaceWith instead of html for assigning text to divMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct typo at `toLocaleTimeString` and remove extra `})` braces

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var loaded = false;

$(function() {
  loaded = true
});

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date()
  var dateTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var divMessage = ''
  if (loaded)
    divMessage = document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green\">" +
    divMessage + ", " + dateTime + "</span>";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divMessage"><span style="color:yellow">some text</span>
</div>
<div id="div2"><span style="color:yellow">some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually the extra brackets was because I have some code there, which I forgot to remove when trying to show my code in a simplifed manner. The problem is still there!

Comment: @Downvoter, May be I am wrong... But Do highlight the mistake so that I can correct it...

Comment: @Rayon Downvoter here. You're not wrong (although OP seems to be unsure whether it actually solves the issue) but that answer is useless nonetheless: Answers pointing out typos are literally only useful to the asker and not to future users.

Comment: @pythonic check in browser console for errors while loading page

Comment: It works here, but in my original code, it doesn't. I have no idea why :(.

Comment: @Kyll – I agree with you but sometimes solving all the typo issues in comments is not feasible.. That is why I go with this answer...

Comment: @Rayon Sure. But if, in the end, the whole issue was caused by typos or unreproducible issues, then an upvoted answer is going to prevent the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from ever deleting the question. So I would advise to at least delete such answers if the questions ends up closed (see the `RemoveAbandonedClosed` label).

Comment: @Kyll – But how will OP get his answer ? We are not helping the cause in that case...

Comment: Do you want to talk about it in [chat]? The comment thread is getting pretty long.

Comment: OK, got it. The problem was in setting divMessage. I was setting it using replaceWith. I needed to use html function there instead!

Comment: @pythonic – I am glad somehow I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If divMessage does not exist in the DOM at page load, [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return null.

> **Elements not in the document** are not searched by getElementById(). When creating an element and assigning it an ID, you have to insert the element into the document tree with Node.insertBefore() or a similar method before you can access it with getElementById()